# How to call where clause with DB::raw inside select

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have three tables named as test_templates, sections and questions. every test_templates contain some sections and each sections may have mulitple questions.Now i want to display the questions count.Also there are three types of questions

1. MCQ's
2. Coding
3. Submission

Individual Count for each type. I tried the below code but it's giving me complete count not for every type individually

```
   foreach ($args['listing'] as $value) {
            $args['sections'][$value->id] = Section::leftJoin('questions','sections.id','=','questions.section_id')
            ->select('sections.template_id','sections.section_name','questions.question_type_id',
                DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (questions.question_type_id = 1) THEN count(questions.id) END) as count_1"),DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (questions.question_type_id = 2) THEN count(questions.id) END) as count_2"),DB::raw("(CASE WHEN (questions.question_type_id = 3) THEN count(questions.id) END) as count_3"))
            ->where('sections.template_id','=',$value->id)
            ->groupBy('sections.id')
            ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I sorted out the above problem such as :

data from these tables and and their count on behalf of a specific type is found in the same query

> ```
> foreach ($args['listing'] as $value) {
>                 $args['sections'][$value->id] = Section::leftJoin('questions','sections.id','=','questions.section_id')
>                 ->select('sections.*','questions.question_type_id'
>                     ,DB::raw('(SELECT count(questions.id) FROM `questions` WHERE `question_type_id` = 1) as mulitple_questions')
>                     ,DB::raw('(SELECT count(questions.id) FROM `questions` WHERE `question_type_id` = 2) as coding_questions')
>                     ,DB::raw('(SELECT count(questions.id) FROM `questions` WHERE `question_type_id` = 3) as submission_questions'))
>                 ->where('sections.template_id','=',$value->id)
>                 ->groupBy('sections.id')
>                 ->get();
>             }
> ```